# What does "completing an elliptic curve $E$ along its identity section $\sigma_0$" mean?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, terminology, formal-groups

From [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/elliptic+curve#EllipticCurvesNodalCurvesCuspidalCurves), I got to know the method of getting formal group/formal group law from Elliptic  from. It says:

> Given an elliptic curve $E$ over $R$, $E\to\text{Spec}(R)$,  we get a formal group $\hat{E}$  by completing $E$ along its identity section $\sigma_0$,
> $$E \to \text{Spec}(R) \stackrel{\sigma_0}{\to} E \,$$
> we get a ringed space $(\hat E, \hat O_{ E,0}) $, then $$ \hat O_{ E\times E,(0,0)}≃ \hat O_{E,0} \hat \otimes_ k \hat O_{E,0}≃k[[x,y]].$$

I have to understand the line, "*we get a formal group $\hat{E}$  by completing $E$ along its identity section $\sigma_0$*".

I know definition of *section*, which is a one way inverse of a morphism. But what does mean by *identity section* ?

Second, what does mean by $\text{completing $E$ along its identity section $\sigma_0$}$ ?

Please explain those two question.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Every fiber of the map $E\to \operatorname{Spec} R$ is a genus one curve; marking a point to be the identity element in the group law on the fiber makes it an honest elliptic curve. The identity section is just this choice made in a coherent way across all fibers. Completion of a scheme along a closed subscheme is a standard construction that you can look up in Hartshorne etc.